# Консоль выводит лишний символ в начале строки

Tags: c, строки

Программа поочередно выводит предложения в которых встречается заданное слово. Консоль при выводе первого предложения добавляет в начало символ 'М'.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    char q[38]="у мамы было мыло. хозяйственное мыло.";
    int i=0, j=0, NP=0;
    char word[5]="мыло";
    char rez[80]="";
    char *P, *start;
    start = &q[0];
    for ( ; ; ) {
        P = strstr(start, word);
        if (P == NULL) break;
        j = P - q;
        i = j;
        while (q[j] != '.')
            j++;
        while ((i >= 0) && (q[i] != '.'))
            i--;
        if (i == -1) { NP = i++; }
        else { NP = i + 2; }
        strncpy(rez,&q[NP],(j - NP + 1));
        rez[j - NP + 2] = '\0';
        rez[79]='\0';
        printf("Искомое предложение:\n");
        puts(rez);
        start = &q[j];
    }
}
```

Выводит :

"Искомое предложение:
Му мамы было мыло.
Искомое предложение:
хозяйственное мыло."

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Comment: `q[38]="у` уберите из кода 38. И посмотрите на длину.

Answer (score 0):

К Вашей программе много замечаний.

Для начала, никогда не пишите так:

```
char q[38]="у мамы было мыло. хозяйственное мыло.";
```

Вы уверены, что умеете считать лучше компьютера? Надо писать так:

```
char q[]="у мамы было мыло. хозяйственное мыло.";
```

Вот эта строка, она вообще - что означает?

```
char rez[80]="";
```

С точки зрения языка, вы пытаетесь инициализировать константный указатель ссылкой на пустую строку. Подозреваю, что (на самом деле) Вы хотели сделать вот это:

```
char rez[80];
rez[0] = '\0';
```

Это выделение буфера размером 80 символов и инициализация его пустой строкой.

Относительно кодировки символов. Вы уверены, что у Вас используется **одно**байтовая кодировка? Потому, что, если это не так, то оператор

```
char word[5]="мыло";
```

становится очень сомнительным.

Общие замечания:

- Программа не имеет ни одного комментария
- Она совершенно не структуирована и запутана.
- Используются лишние переменные

Я немного упростил Вашу программу и получилось вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main()
{
    char q[]="у мамы было мыло. Хозяйственное мыло. И зубная паста ";
    char word[]="мыло";
    char rez[128];
    char *point;   // Указатель на найденную точку
    char *q_copy;  // Рабочий указатель для движения по исходной строке
    int len;       // Длина найденного предложения
    
    q_copy = q;  // Создаём рабочую копию указателя

    // Цикл, пока можем найти точку в конце предложения
    while ( (point = index(q_copy, '.')) != NULL) {
        // Выделяем очередное предложение из строки
        len = point - q_copy;
        strncpy(rez, q_copy, len);
        rez[len] = '\0';
        
        // Проверяем наличие искомого слова
        if (strstr(rez, word) != NULL)
            printf("Искомое предложение: '%s'\n", rez);
            
        // Переходим к следующему предложению
        q_copy = point + 1; 
    }
}
```

Программу тестировал под Linux, так что, если будут проблемы с кодировкой - разбирайтесь сами :-)

Comment: `Вот эта строка, она вообще - что означает?` Как бы это инициализация, которую ТС делает неправильно. Там нет присваивания. И еще, в `C` нет ссылок!!..